# How do I convert a .swf file to HTML5 and make changes in the code?

Tags: html5, flash, file-conversion

I have an animation (`.swf`) that I want to convert to HTML5 and then edit a few of the links that appears in the animation. I have tried Google Swiffy and it outputs something that works really well but is not editable. It just links to some external library.

To clarify, what I need is a tool to do this:

1. Convert (`.swf`) file to HTML5.
2. Output the actual HTML, CSS and JavaScript to files so that they are easily editable and not dependant on external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.statsilk.com/blog/flash-versus-html5-wallaby-and-swiffy-conversion-tools-review), there's a tool from Adobe that generates editable HTML and Javascript: [Wallaby](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/).

Among other tools, [PixelPlant](http://www.pixelplant.com/) looks nice.

Comment: Wallaby is for .fla files. I tried PixelPlant. Interesting tool, but unfortunately the HTML5 output didn't work properly in Internet Explorer 10, and probably not in IE9 either. I really tried to edit the code manually to make it work but I couldn't do it. I ended up using a different approach. I Used SWF Unlocker to unlock the .swf file, then imported it into Flash Decompiler Trillix. I managed to change all the fields and save it as an .swf file. Your advice did not solve the problem, but you did answer my original question and thus you will get the reward.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many software and online tools are available.. http://www.flashconvertermac.com/swf-to-html5-converter.html use this page to download the software to convert SWF to HTML5 or use https://pixelplant.com/‎ for online conversion.